# issue with loop increments of lower than 1 when simulating data

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, random

I'm trying to simulate data utulizing a for loop and storing it in some matrix with the following code:

```
m <- matrix(nrow = 500 , ncol = 7)

for(i in seq(from =  1, to = 4, by = 0.5)){
  
    a <- 1 * i + rnorm(n = 500, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    m[, i] <- a
}
```

But instead of giving me 7 columns with means of roughly 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5 and 4.  matrix m contains 4 columns with means of roughly 1.5, 2.5, 3.5 and 4 and 3 columns of NA values.

If i change the increments to 1 and run the below code, everything behaves as expected so the issue seems to be with the increments, but i cant figure out what i should do differently, help would be most appreciated.

```
m <- matrix(nrow = 500 , ncol = 7)

for(i in seq(from =  1, to = 7, by = 1)){
  
    a <- 1 * i + rnorm(n = 500, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    m[, i] <- a
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Column indices must be integers. In your case, you try to select column `1.5` which is not possible. You can fix this by some simple calculations (`(i * 2) - 1`)

```r
# reduce number of rows for showcase
n <- 100
m <- matrix(nrow = n , ncol = 7)

for(i in seq(from =  1, to = 4, by = 0.5)){
  
  # NOTE: 1*i does not change anything
  a <- 1*i + rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  
  # make column index integerish
  m[, (i * 2) - 1] <- a
}
m[1:5, ]
#>             [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]
#> [1,]  1.15699467 0.8917952 1.999899 2.330557 4.502607 4.469957 5.687460
#> [2,] -1.13634309 1.5394771 1.700148 1.669329 2.124019 3.472836 3.513351
#> [3,]  2.08584731 1.0591743 2.866186 3.192953 3.984286 3.593902 3.983265
#> [4,]  0.02211767 2.2222376 2.055832 2.927851 2.846376 3.411725 3.742966
#> [5,]  0.49167319 2.2244472 2.190050 3.525931 2.841522 5.722172 4.797856

colMeans(m)
#> [1] 0.8537568 1.6805235 1.9907633 2.6434843 2.8651140 3.5499583 3.9757984
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `rnorm`, it actually allows vectorzied input for the mean value, so you can try the code below (but you should use `matrix` to fit the obtained output into the desired dimensions of your output matrix)

```
nr <- 500
nc <- 7
m <- t(matrix(rnorm(nr * nc, seq(1, 4, 0.5), 1), nc, nr))
```

where you can see, for example

```
> m[1:5, ]
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]
[1,]  3.2157776 0.3805689 0.7550255 2.508356 3.567479 2.597378 4.122201
[2,]  0.8634009 0.4887092 2.5655513 1.710756 2.377790 3.733045 4.199812
[3,] -0.1786419 2.4471083 1.2138140 3.090687 2.763694 3.471715 4.676037
[4,]  1.2492511 2.3480447 2.2180039 1.965656 1.505342 3.832380 4.086075
[5,] -0.1301543 1.7463687 1.2467769 2.649525 4.795677 2.606623 4.318468

> colMeans(m)
[1] 0.901146 1.476423 1.900147 2.567463 2.996918 3.468140 4.025929
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `i` as a row index, but `i` has non-integer values. Only integers can be used for indexing a matrix/df. When `i` is, say, 1.5 but you try to use it in the `m[,i]` expression, it gets forced into an integer and rounded down to 1, so the first 2 runs of your loop overwrite each other (and the 3rd and 4th, etc.).

You could simply use your second code and replace `1*i` with `0.5 + 0.5*i`:

```
m <- matrix(nrow = 5000 , ncol = 7)

for(i in seq(from =  1, to = 7, by = 1)){
  
    a <- 0.5 + 0.5*i + rnorm(n = 5000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    m[,i] <- a
}
```

However, it may be better to use the params of the `rnorm` function to generate values with a specified mean/sd: currently, you are drawing from a normal distribution centered around 0 *then* shifting it sideways; you could simply tell it to use the mean you actually want.

```
m <- matrix(nrow = 5000 , ncol = 7)

for(i in seq(from =  1, to = 7, by = 1)){
  
    m[,i] <- rnorm(n = 5000, mean = 0.5 + 0.5*i, sd = 1)
}
```